# item jumps to the left while dragging

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```js
$('#titles').sortable({
 containment: "parent",
 axis: "y",
 helper: "clone",
 tolerance: "pointer",
});
```

```css
.grida{
 position:fixed;
 left:0; top:29px; width:100%;
 height:calc(100% - 29px);
 overflow:hidden;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:134px auto;
 grid-gap: 5px;
 padding:5px;
}

.titles{
 height:calc(100% - 30px);
 overflow-y:scroll;
 padding:7px 0;
}

.title{
 margin:2px 0;
 padding:2px 7px;
 cursor:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='grida'>
<div class='before'>before</div>
<div class='titles' id='titles'>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Why is `title` jumping to the left while dragging?

I tried withotut `grida` (just plain `titles` div as parent) and it works fine.

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0):

It comes from `position`. `grida` class has `position: fixed;`.In fixed position, final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. `grida` has `left:0; top:29px;` and so, it causes jumping to left.

**Solution**

You can add `position: relative;` to `titles` that the children elements of `titles` e.g `title` is positioned relative to its normal position.

```
.titles {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 7px 0;
  position: relative;  /*Add this*/
}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/bfuoLh42/9/)